# what's difference between RTGoalHandle and RTGoalHandleFollow?

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In joint_trajectory_action_controller.h (robot_mechanism_controllers package).

RTGoalHandle is defined as RTServerGoalHandle<[pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryAction](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/electric/api/pr2_controllers_msgs/html/structpr2__controllers__msgs_1_1JointTrajectoryAction__.html)> and RTGoalHandleFollow is defined as RTServerGoalHandle<[control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/electric/api/control_msgs/html/structcontrol__msgs_1_1FollowJointTrajectoryAction__.html)>

What does these two types use for? It seems their API looks really similar.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64431/what%27s-difference-between-rtgoalhandle-and-rtgoalhandlefollow?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The JointTrajectoryActionController supports three ways to command trajectories:

- Using the raw `trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory` topic interface
- Using the `pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryAction` action interface
- Using the `control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction` action interface.

It is my understanding that `FollowJointTrajectoryAction` superceeds the `JointTrajectoryAction` interface. The main difference between the two is that `FollowJointTrajectoryAction` allows you to specify path and goal tolerances in the action goal. These tolerances are optional, and if unspecified defaults specified in the parameter server are used. The older `JointTrajectoryAction` only used tolerances from the parameter server.

As to the `RTGoalHandle*`, they are convenience instances that allow a realtime controller to implement an actionlib server.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1